# How can I transform a query string generated by a search form into new URL without the query string?

Tags: php, .htaccess, search, redirect, query-string

I have a search form that on submit generates something like this url:

```
http://mydomain.com/index.php?find=some+text
```

And I'm aiming to make it look like:

```
http://mydomain.com/find/some+text
```

How can I do this with .htaccess ?

So far I have this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &?find=(.*)&?
RewriteRule ^index.php$ find/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^find/(.*)$ index.php?find=$1 [L]
```

This works if the query (i.e what I search for) contains only numbers, letters or underscore, but I want to make it capable of search for anything including spaces and other characters!

Comment: That looks like it might get you stuck in a loop?

Answer (score 1):

So, it seams that the 404 error was being cause because of some configuration in the web server that did not permit URLs to have + (plus sign).
It would break at the first + and try to find a file by that name.

Having that sorted out the rewrite rules were like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /*.index\.php\?find=([^&\.]+)?\sHTTP
RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ /find/%1? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?find/(.*)$ /index.php?find=$1 [L,NC]
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't something like this work?

```
RewriteRule ^find/([^/]*)$ /index.php?find=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for you reply. It will not work if query var find has a space for instance. And also would only work if i was to type find/sometext myself or have in in a link, and I need it to come from a form submit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to match against the actual request and not the URI because the URI gets rewritten via your second rule. This causes a redirect loop.

To redirect the browser:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?find=([^&\.]+)(&([^\ ]+))?
RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ /find/%1?%3 [L,R=301]
```

To internally rewrite it back

```
RewriteRule ^/?find/(.*)$ /index.php?find=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank for your reply! Hum.. I don't know if that was the problem but it makes sense. Even so..with this version I still can't preform a search with more that one word as it will return 404.